# Spring - Autowiring vs manual method call

Tags: java, spring

I saw a lot of examples of this (option 1):

```
@Bean A a(){
  return new A();
}

@Bean B b(){
  return a().makeB();
}
```

What are advantages of this comparing to (option 2):

```
@Bean A a(){
  return new A();
}

@Bean B b(A a){
  return a.makeB();
}
```

From what I can tell, using option 1 it is easier to navigate between beans (but with support from IDE, it is as easy to do so in option 2 also). Downside is I guess coupling, so in tests it is harder to overwrite bean A in bean B, since it is directly referenced (in option 1).

Is there any other particular reason to use option 1 (eg. speed, or smthn.)?

Comment: Would example one create another `A` instead to create `B`, where example two injects the bean `A`, thus you only create one instance?

Comment: @Tom see my answer. Configuration classes are always proxied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no reason** to use *option 1* at all.
I don't even know when this notation was first used.
However, unlike what you'd think, this

```
a().makeB();
```

does not actually call the method `a()` directly.
*Option 1* does infact **not** create another instance of the class, instead the call is *proxied* and the *Bean* is either created (reaching the method), if none were present, or re-used, if a *singleton*. Thank you `BeanFactory`!

`CGLIB` is doing a lot for you in the background.

```
intercept:319, ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor
```

[image]

---

Anyway, as a matter of simplicitly and usability inside the IDE, *option 2* is the way to go, always.
With *option 2*, you'll also be able to **clearly see the dependencies** for a *Bean*.

Addressing the performance concerns, no, there is no real difference. And you shouldn't really worry about those minor details. Spring uses *proxies/interceptors* everywhere.